# How to make this fib sequence faster?

Tags: javascript

```
var fibonacci = function(n) {
    let cache = {};
    let value;
    if (n in cache) {
        value = cache[n];
    } else {
        if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
            value = n;
        } else {
            value = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
            cache[n] = value;
        }enter code here
    }
    return value;
};

fibonacci(60)
```

---

codewar wont accept this fib sequence its too slow how to make it faster

Comment: You can use `Binet's Formula` and round up or cache up to `n` and resume from there when input > n.

Answer (score 0):

Put the cache *outside* of the function, otherwise it won't do anything (subsequent calls of `fibonacci`, including the recursive calls, won't be able to see prior cached numbers):

```js
let cache = {};
var fibonacci = function(n) {
  let value;
  if (n in cache) {
    value = cache[n];
  } else {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
      value = n;
    } else {
      value = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
      cache[n] = value;
    }
  }
  return value;
};

console.log(fibonacci(60))
```

To clean up the code some more, you can immediately `return` instead, to cut down on indentation and to avoid unnecessary reassignment:

```js
const cache = {};
const fibonacci = function(n) {
  if (n in cache) {
    return cache[n];
  }
  if (n <= 1) {
    return n;
  }
  const value = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
  cache[n] = value;
  return value;
};

console.log(fibonacci(60))
```

Keep in mind that this `fibonacci` will still only be accurate up to a certain point. Once the return value is larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (9007199254740991), it will be inaccurate. If that's a possibility, use and return BigInts instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using two recursion results in very bad perofrmance (good for understanding recursion). You need to use loops and array beside memoization for good performance. After all heavy computation blocks main thread in JavaScript hence not a good choice for heavy computation applications.

> 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, ...

```
const cache = [1, 1]

function fibonacci(n) {
  if (n <= cache.length) {
    return cache[n - 1]
  }
  for (let i = cache.length; i < n; i++) {
    cache[i] = cache[i - 1] + cache[i - 2]
  }
  return cache[n - 1]
}
```

To avoid using global you can use [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)):

```
function fibonacci(m) {
  const cache = [1, 1]
  return (function (n) {
    if (n <= cache.length) {
      return cache[n - 1]
    }
    for (let i = cache.length; i < n; i++) {
      cache[i] = cache[i - 1] + cache[i - 2]
    }
    return cache[n - 1]
  })(m)
}
```

This is an example of [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) using [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) and [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Answer (score 0):

Using a loop instead of recursion is faster, and if you use array destructuring it's more readable.

a = fn-1 and b = fn-2

```
function fibonacci(n) {
    if (n === 0) return 0;
    if (n === 1) return 1;

    let [a, b] = [0, 1];
    for (var i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        [a, b] = [b, a + b];
    }

    return b;
}
```